# Pointers on Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, pointers, nsstring, dereference

From what I understand (and please correct me if I'm wrong):

```
int x, count = 10;
int *hello;
hello = &count;
x = *hello;
```

Here the variables x and count are declared to be of type integer. Additionally, the variable count is assigned the value of 10.

hello is a pointer to type integer. hello is then assigned the address of count.
In order to access the value of count, hello must have an asterisk in front of it, ie, *hello.

So, x is assigned the value of whatever is in count and in this case, 10.

However...

```
Fraction *myFraction = [[Fraction alloc] init];
[myFraction someMethod];
```

Here, if I understand correctly, myFraction is a pointer to an instance of Fraction class.

myFraction is pointing to (or rather assigned the address of) an object which has been assigned memory and initialised.

Surely, in order to access the object that myFraction points to, I ought to write:

```
 [*myFraction someMethod];
```

Given the way in which x accessed the value of count, surely in order to access the object, one ought to write this and not:

```
[myFraction someMethod];
```

In addition, if I have

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
NSString *str = @"Programming can be a headache";
NSLog (@"%@\n", str);
```

Why is str being treated as an object above? Or is str an object and in which case, why would I want to make it point to an instance of NSString class? Surely, I ought to be able to just assign an object to str?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All the usage of objects in objective c is done through object references, e.g. pointers.

- The Objective C syntax lets you treat objects without dereferencing them, this is different than C / C++ for that matter.
- `str` is an object reference of type `NSString` (as `myFraction`) and `@"Programming can be a headache"` is an object reference of type `NSString` as well, so you can assign it to `str`.

Comment: So if I get it,when I have:
NSString *pointer;
pointer=[[NSString alloc]init];//here pointer is assigned a memory address!
pointer=@"value of pointer";//here is where I should use dereference but i'm not?(*pointer=@"value of pointer")..is this right?

Comment: You should not dereference the pointer when assigning to it, as the pointer itself should contain the address of the object. so no need for `*pointer = @"string"`, only `pointer = @"String"`

Comment: from the "int" example i made in my question i would expect "*pointer" to mean :"give me the value/object stored by 'pointer' variable address"...instead when I just have "pointer" without asterisk i expect to be dealing with a memory address.. is this correct?? don't know if i get it

Comment: Basically you are right, but bear in mind that objects references are pointer, and you never access the object directly, alway its reference.

Comment: let's say i have : NSString *str=[[NSString alloc]initwithstring:@"init string"]; //I know the address is 0x35b8..whenever i assign some text like str = @"assigned text" the address pointed is different (0x35d8).. could I access the text under the old (0x35b8) memory address? and is this approach correct since when I read "*str" I understand "gimme the object/value stored under 'str' address"??

Comment: No, once you lose the reference, you can't access the data. (unless you assigned it to another variable)

Answer (score 1):

Additional to Binyamin

- Everything inside the brackets [  ] is objective-C and not simple C  (so [*object message] is not common to use)
- [object message], you send the "message" to your object, and the object responds with something (he can return something or he can do something without anything in return).
- Everything with a * on the left is pointer. So *str is a pointer. And where is it point? to an object NSString. The @"blabla" returns the adress of one CONSTANT string that has generated directly by the compiler.
- NSLog (@"%@\n", str); here the %@ calls the **+Description class** method of NSString object called str. By default the description of an NSString Object returns the value of the string (the text). %@ is not a simple replace like the %d with numbers (int,double etc). All objects have +Description method that inherit from the NSObject (note is Class method and not instant).

***description***

Returns a string that represents the contents of the receiving class.

- (NSString *)description